# How to define content within a custom region?

Tags: blocks

I'm new to Drupal and I'm only learning. I'm required to add a custom region to my site. I understand what I must add in the .info file and set from Structure > Blocks to make it show up. What I don't understand is where do I write the content for my "custom region block"?

Say I've a region I want to call "my_region". What do I do to actually define how the "my_region" is supposed to look like?

I've tried various online reference sites and most of them just show me how to do this -

```
regions[header] = Header
```

and this-

```
        <?php if ($page['header']): ?>
        <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I know all that. What I don't know is how to make regions['my_region'] work.

Any references to tutorials or guides would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you

EDIT:

I've set up a region in the info file as `regions['my_region'] = MyRegion`.
Now I'm clueless as to where to add the contents that goes in `regions['my_region']` or any other custom content that I define?

Example: If I want `regions['my_region']` to include a slideshow, where do I actually create the file containing the slideshow that `regions['my_region']` refers to?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You know what to do, you provided valid code samples. So what's your real problem? What exactly happens? What error messages you got? Or you added 'my_region' and simply don't see it anywhere? If so, post your actual code samples. We need more data to help you. We need to know what are you really asking.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Consider updating title too. Now it looks out of sync with a body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regions are nothing more than a block holders. To add content to a region, go to http://example.com/admin/structure/block *(substitute example.com with your real domain of course)*, and just drag and drop slideshow block to "MyRegion" region.